# Check Facebook app is still functional (without a Facebook account)

Tags: facebook

I've inherited a website that has a little Facebook app to show posts. I have the app ID / secret / graph URL and I've managed to establish a fair bit of info like the owner, access token, name, link, etc. The app is currently returning no data, and the "link" leads to a 404. Is there a way to establish if an app has been deleted / is no longer functional, without an FB developer account? (Yes i could contact the owner but that's not currently feasible).

Comment: If you can still request info about the app id via API using an app access token, then it can’t have been deleted. “Functional” could mean anything and nothing though.

Comment: Yes that helps, if it returns any info about the app then it's still "live" then (regardless of whether it's actually doing what it should be doing). Thanks.